# Grouping and Sub-queries dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, cube, ssas-tabular

I am bringing detailed data to Tabular cube(Model is denormalized..One table in model having various  attributes A,B,C,D and measures).I want to calculate some measures(Sales, Unit Price) by grouping on A.B.C. On top of that i want to calculate few measures on grouping of B.C.D and first level measures(sales,unit price) will be used to calculate the second level(new) measures..This is what we can achieve by using sub queries in sql. How to write them in dax.

Evaluate
                            GROUPBY(
                            ADDCOLUMNS( 
GROUPBY(

```
EMP,
    EMP[Visitid],EMP[Identifier],EMP[Specifier],EMP[SystemId],EMP[Login]
    ) ,"Status", IF([Min_ResponseId]=88,"N","Y"),
              "Resolved", [Max_StatusId],
     "Max_createdate",Max(EMP[CreateDate])
     ),
        EMP[Login],EMP[Identifier],EMP[Specifier],
    "Accepted",MAXX(  CURRENTGROUP (), IF([Resolved]=7 && [Status]="Y",1,0) )
    )
```

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you've attempted (at the very least).

Comment: Sql - Select Sum(yy) from A group by x,y,z  - result stored in temp table